# validation with one fixed training set

Tags: bootstrap, validation

I'm wondering is it reasonable if I use the fix training set, and instead have 10 different subsets of validation set with the same size?
So, I separate 70% of original dataset and estimate my model once, then I draw 10 random subsets with the size of 20% from the leftover which was 30% of whole data. 
Does it seem a correct way? if yes, can you introduce a reference as I need to provide a support for my approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This approach is valid in the sense that you are evaluating your model on data that were not used for training. So far so good.

Besides that, it does not make much sense. Firstly, if you take random subsamples of your validation data (10 subsamples, 20% each), they will not be independent of each other (since some points will repeat in different subsamples). Moreover, each of these small samples will have lower information value than if you used all of them together, because each of them will cover smaller portion of the input space compared to the whole validation set.

One of the points of performing cross-validation is to see how does your model perform when trained on different training sets, i.e. how stable results it can produce. By fixing the training set, you lose this benefit.

If you want to use a fixed training dataset (for whatever reason), then just use all of the remaining samples for single validation.